# Git - get file from another branch to a specific folder in current branch

Tags: git

I have a file `data.yml` in `logistics/dev/raw_to_ods/folder1` directory in dev branch. And I need to move it to master branch to `logistics/prod/raw_to_ods/folder1` directory.
But when I use `git checkout dev logistics/dev/raw_to_ods/folder1` git creates `logistics/dev/raw_to_ods/folder1/data.yml` in master branch.
But in my case I need `data.yml` file in  `logistics/prod/raw_to_ods/folder1/`
What git command should I use in my case?

Comment: Once the file exists, why not just move it normally?

Comment: `git mv` also exists, if you like.

Comment: File doesn't exist in master branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+checkout+file+different+directory

Comment: `git show dev:logistics/dev/raw_to_ods/folder1/data.yml > logistics/prod/raw_to_ods/folder1/data.yml`

Answer (score 0):

1. `git stash` (saves your local changes)
2. `git checkout theOtherBranchName` (allows you to change branches ofc)
3. `git stash pop` (sends your local changes saved in the place where you are, can sometimes cause a merge if there are conflicts between the 2 branches which is normal)
4. Move your file where you needs